# "Cannot read property 'nationalCode' of undefined" error in redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I use redux-form for my reactjs applicaion, in validate.js file when i want validate my formSection "personFields" code will occur with "Cannot read property 'nationalCode' of undefined" error

```
// validate.js file

export default values => {
    const errors = {};

    errors.personFields = validatePersonFields(values.personFields);

    return errors
};

const validatePersonFields = values => {
    const errors = {};

    if (!values.nationalCode) {
        errors.nationalCode = 'it is required';
    }

    return errors;
};
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`values.personFields` must be `undefined`:

```
const validatePersonFields = (values = {}) => {
    const errors = {};

    if (!values.nationalCode) {
        errors.nationalCode = 'it is required;
    }

    return errors;
};
```

This will at least allow you to continue when no field values are present.